# how to connect remote docker container mysql server

Tags: mysql, magento, docker, docker-container

is there any way to connect remote docker container mysql server?

I am installing **magento** web application, now I have a situation like I need to use/point the existing **remote docker container database**. I have make port forwarding in order to access database from remote machine but it doe not work.

```
docker run -it -d -p 3002:80 -h tm.gworks.mobi -v /var/www/public --privileged --name database magedev
```

For testing purpose in remote machine I have tried like `mysql -u root -h 192.168.1.21:3002 -p` in mysql console but it does not connect, it throws error `ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '192.168.1.21:3002' (-2)`

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with that question. please mention the reason for down vote, otherwise the mistakes is still remain

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: please read once again, this question related to docker not magento. I thought the screenshot confused. actually I need to access remote docker mysql server, thats it. In remote machine we can't mention docker ip as a mysql host so I have make port forwarding but it does not works. Please mention in comment if I wrong I will delete this question.

Comment: It's still not about programming. This is a programming forum. You need to post it elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker run command should be,

```
docker run -it -d -p 3002:3306 -h tm.gworks.mobi -v /var/www/public --privileged --name database magedev
```

default mysql port is **3306** but I listen port **80** which is my nginx port so it can't be to allow.

```
mysql -u root -h 192.168.1.21 -P 3002 -p
```

now everything works fine